# Combine two javascript calls into one involving a GET-request

Tags: javascript

I need to make a GET request to retrieve a string and then pass that string onto another external javascript file. How can I combine an external Javascript file with a GET request?

In the problem below, I retrieve a value for the "token" variable and then want to pass it on to the second  tag to use it in the "data-token" part.

Is there a way to combine these two actions into one  tag? The way I am doing it now does not work and I have a hard time finding a solution. Probably due to my inexperience with javascript and not knowing the right terminology.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('https://demo4661814.mockable.io/monkey', function(data) {
        token = data['msg'] // token = "txn_c3983f0bce163a0eb2b427c7a977eecd"
    });
</script>

<script src="https://js.mockio.com/scripts/mockio.js" 
    data-token=token
    data-additional="name,address,phone">
</script>
```

Comment: Declare `token` as a global variable outside the GET function

Comment: That wouldn't help as the request would be asynchronous. The script file next file would get token as undefined or whatever it is initialized globally with.

Answer (score 1):

You can `write` the later tag in to the `document` when you get the result from the get script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('https://demo4661814.mockable.io/monkey', function(data) {
        token = data['msg'] // token = "txn_c3983f0bce163a0eb2b427c7a977eecd"
        document.write('<script src="https://js.mockio.com/scripts/mockio.js" data-token=' + token + ' data-additional="name,address,phone"></script>');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the script tag dynamically after retrieving the token:

```
$.getJSON('https://demo4661814.mockable.io/monkey', function(data) {
    var token = data['msg']; // token = "txn_c3983f0bce163a0eb2b427c7a977eecd"

    $('<script>')
        .attr('src', 'https://js.mockio.com/scripts/mockio.js')
        .attr('data-token', token)
        .attr('data-additional', 'name,address,phone')
        .appendTo('body');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single API which would serve both your requests.

By which I mean,

Create an API endpoint for example say it is, https://js.mockio.com/intermediateAPI. This API would internally request for https://demo4661814.mockable.io/monkey and would get the token. Once this request is successful and the response is received, the API would request for https://js.mockio.com/scripts/mockio.js with the token received from the above request and would serve the response to the user.